# Expressjs POST error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: node.js, post, express

I tried a lot to figure out why this raises this error:

```
Configuring
Listening on 2000
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
   at /home/abdulsattar/learning/node/express/index.js:9:20
```

The index.js:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express.createServer();

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send('<form action="/new" method="post"><input type="text" name="title" /><input type="submit" /></form>');
});

app.post("/new", function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.body.title);
});

app.configure(function() {
  console.log("Configuring");
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 2000;

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

I've read that express needs the `bodyParser()`. I `use`d it above, but it always fails. I tried it on versions `2.5.8` and `2.5.8` (thinking that could be the problem) but it failed on both the versions. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My hunch, try moving your app.configure statement before your app.get and app.post. The bodyParser middleware isn't being called. Also, to be safe add the `enctype` to the form, shouldn't be necessary, but regardless: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Let me know...

Comment: Oh, Man! That was it! I moved the configure statement before the handlers and it worked. Thanks a lot!